# How to force CAJA browser to respect umask setting when creating a new folder/file with right click?

Tags: permissions, nautilus, mate, ubuntu-mate, caja

In the latest Ubuntu LTS with MATE Desktop, newly created folders and files from the CAJA browser appear always with read permission for all users, no matter what value I assign with umask in /etc/profile, which is a serious privacy backdoor.

I am sure there must be some configuration file hidden inside somewhere, so that CAJA can create the folders and files that can only read by me and my group, for instance.

Comment: I would recommend to ask this question also on http://ubuntu-mate.community/ to get more relevant results.